# How to annotate random matrix in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following which generates a random matrix image (first example).  But I can't figure out how to:

1. correct the shape of the cells in the top and right
2. add color tint (blue in second example)
3. make it into outlined chunks (second example)

   ```
   \begin{figure}[p]
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
      \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,...,.9} {
          \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,.9} {
              \pgfmathparse{0.9*rnd+0.3}
              \definecolor{MyColor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult}
                  \node[fill=MyColor,inner sep=0.1cm,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center] at (\x,\y) {}; 
          }
      }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
   ```

Output (example 1):

[image]

I demonstrate these steps in example 2, but I was only able to get it working from a pre-generated pdf file:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[inner sep=0pt] (tumor1to4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim=0 400 400 0,clip,width=20ex,height=20ex]{Plots/Clipart/heatmap.pdf}};

     \node[right=1ex of tumor1to4,font=\fontsize{20}{0}\selectfont, thick] (el1) {...};
     
     \node[inner sep=0pt, right= 0.5ex of el1] (tumorp) {\includegraphics[trim=0 400 475 0,clip,height=20ex]{Plots/Clipart/heatmap.pdf}};
 
     \node[right=0.5ex of tumorp,font=\fontsize{20}{0}\selectfont, thick] (el2) {...};
     
     \node[inner sep=0pt, right= 0.5ex of el2] (tumorP) {\includegraphics[trim=475 400 0 0,clip,height=20ex]{Plots/Clipart/heatmap.pdf}};
 
    \node[below=3ex of tumor1to4,font=\fontsize{20}{0}\selectfont, thick, rotate=90] (el3) {...};
 
     \node[inner sep=0pt, below =5.5ex of tumor1to4] (tumorK) {\includegraphics[trim=0 300 400 178,clip,width=20ex]{Plots/Clipart/heatmap.pdf}};

     \node[right=1ex of tumorK,font=\fontsize{20}{0}\selectfont, thick] (el5) {...};
     
     \node[inner sep=0pt, right= 0.5ex of el5] (tumorKp) {\includegraphics[trim=0 300 475 178,clip,width=5ex]{Plots/Clipart/heatmap.pdf}};
 
     \node[right=0.5ex of tumorKp,font=\fontsize{20}{0}\selectfont, thick] (el6) {...};
     
     \node[inner sep=0pt, right= 0.5ex of el6] (tumorKP) {\includegraphics[trim=475 300 0 178,clip,height=5ex]{Plots/Clipart/heatmap.pdf}};
    
     \node[draw=red,size=3pt,rectangle,fit=(tumorp) (tumorKp)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output (example 2):

[image]

Now the question is, how to I annotate example 1 as in example 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, with `inner sep=0.1cm` every node actually has size 0.2cm x 0.2cm. This caused the shape problem of the cells in the top and right.

Here I use `inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1cm` instead. You may choose another base color and random color range, instead of `blue` and `[-75, 75]` respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1cm]
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., 9} {
        % add vertical shift and dots
        \ifnum\y=2\relax
          \tikzset{yshift=-1cm}
        \else
          \ifnum\y=1\relax
            \path node at (5, \y+1) {\huge$\vdots$};
          \fi
        \fi
        
        \foreach \x in {1, ..., 9} {
            % add horizontal shift and dots
            \ifnum\x<8\relax
            \else
              \tikzset{xshift=1cm*(\x-7)}
              \ifnum\y=1\relax
              \path node at (\x-1, 5) {\huge\ldots}
                    node at (\x-1, 1) {\huge\ldots};
              \fi
            \fi
            
            % get random color
            \pgfmathparse{int(150*rnd-75)} % [-75, 75]
            % color range: blue!75!white .. blue!100 .. blue!75!black
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax
              \colorlet{MyColor}{black!\pgfmathresult!blue}
            \else
              \edef\pgfmathresult{-\pgfmathresult}
              \colorlet{MyColor}{white!\pgfmathresult!blue}
            \fi
            
            % draw filled square
            \node[fill=MyColor] at (\x,\y) {};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's impressive, thanks